# how to click each row in my table layout?

Tags: android, onclick, tablelayout, tablerow

How can I click each row and column of my `TabelLayout`?.

I don't know how to handle click event in a `TableLayout`. If I click a row that wish to show images in, I think I need to handle the click event. I am confused please help me friends.

This is my xml design and xml source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPicture4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" >
            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name : Tom"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company : TCS"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone : 12345"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPicture4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" >
            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name : Tom"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company : Infosys"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone : 45678"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPicture4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" >
            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name : Tom"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company : TCS"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone : 12345"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPicture4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" >
            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name : Tom"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Company : Infosys"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone : 45678"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: you want click on each item or a row? your table row has 2 items in it.

Comment: i want to click each item yashwanth....

Comment: Is the content of your TableLayout really static? You need to design your activity using the TableLayout as a container and use an Adapter to bind real data to your view. Using that approach, you could implement an onItemClick method…

Comment: do you plan to load the data dynamically? or through xml?

Comment: Please give me some sample link renaud. it's very help to me....

Comment: I plan to load dynamically yashwanth. please help me...am new for android

Comment: now I created static table layout design. please help me how to click each item in this design.